# Tomcat to WebSphere - Server Contexts

Tags: tomcat, websphere

I have a line that defines the location of reports and images in my Tomcat setup that has the following data:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="/usr/local/app/oid/reports" path="/appreports" workDir="work/Catalina/localhost/appreports">
</Context>
```

and:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="/usr/local/app/oid/images" path="/appimages" workDir="work/Catalina/localhost/appimages">
</Context>
```

How would I go about setting these up inside of WebSphere? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this through my searching. It's also very possible the terminology I'm  using may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your applications on WAS using the console, you'll have a step in the wizard wich will allow you to customize context path.

IIRC it is at step 7 or 8 in install wizard.